# Creating and executing shell scripts to run XAMPP on double click

Tags: command-line, 13.10, scripts, xampp

**Basic Specs** - Ubuntu 13.10, Gnome 3 (session fallback), Ambiance theme, Faenza icons.

I recently installed [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/index.html), now everytime i want to use the program i have to run the `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start` command, im quite new at ubuntu but i know my way around some things and i knew i can make a shell script to start the program when i double click on it, so, i open nano in the terminal and write:

```
#!/bin/bash/
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

I save it as "lampp.sh" at my home dir and give it the proper permissions `chmod +x lampp.sh` and `chmod +775 lampp.sh`. When i double click on it absolutely nothing happens, in order for it to work i have to open a terminal and run the the script there `./lampp.sh`.

If i have to open the terminal each time i want to run the script then the script it self is worthless (specially when runing the `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start` is 1 line of code), is there anyway i can run it on double click?

Thanks in advance, i love this community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opening stanza should be

```
#!/bin/bash
```

... There isn't a trailing slash.

`sudo` is also going to want a password every time. You can either:

- Add an exception to `/etc/sudoers`
- Use a graphical `sudo` equivalent like `pkexec` or `gksudo`

I think on balance, just substituting in `pkexec` is the easiest solution.

Comment: Thanks @Oli im using the `gksudo` equivalent, its exactly what i was looking for, the password prompt is not a problem, in fact its better. Im reading about editing the sudoers now.